# JQuery change inner text but preserve html

Tags: jquery

I would like to change the text of a HTML element but preserve the rest of the inner html with jQuery.

For instance:

```
<a href="link.html">Some text <img src="image.jpg" /></a>
```

replace "Some text" with "Other text", and the result should look like:

```
<a href="link.html">Other text <img src="image.jpg" /></a>
```

**EDIT:
My current solution is following:**

```
var aElem = $('a');
var children = aElem.children();

aElem.text("NEW TEXT");
aElem.append(children);
```

But there must be some more elegant way of doing this.

Comment: u want to change the value but on which event??

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This seems to work just fine.

<kbd>**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6SnjB/)**</kbd>

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="link.html">Some text <img src="img.jpg" /></a>
    </body>

    </html>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            var $link = $('a');
            var $img = $link.find('img'); 
            $link.html('New Text');
            $link.append($img);
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Yes this is similar to my current solution. I use the children() property instead and reinsert the children into the element. This works fine, but I was wondering if there is any better solution.

Comment: You should use `$link.children('img')` instead of `find()` method because you want direct children. Use `find()` to search through grandchildren.

Comment: This solution works fine as long as you don't have any event listeners binded to the HTML inside the `<a>` tag. Otherwise, you will have to add those listeners again.

Answer (score 37):

Since you can't modify the link an option would be to simply use `replace`

```
$("a").html($("a").html().replace("Some text", "Other text"));
```

Example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/J5LHV/).

Comment: Why the down vote? using this method would preserve the original markup. Ex. `<a><img/>Some text<img/> </a> ` with detach/reattach results in `<a>Other Text<img/><img/></a>` while using a simple replace maintains the structure.

Comment: What if the `<img>` tag contains `Some text` ??

Comment: I don't know why I downvoted your answer, must have been a mistake.
Just saw a “+9” on my score and wondered why one point was missing and saw my downvote here.
I can't revoke the downvote until the answer is edited :/

Comment: A bit naive, right? I voted this down because obviously the string "Some text" won't be the one being replaced when deployed. This will of course be other strings in a dynamic site. Therefore it's impossible to rely on string matching like this.

Comment: Could be improved by caching the jQuery selection

Comment: Also this replaces only the first occurrence. If you want to replace it more than once, [RegExp will do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript).

Answer (score 23):

Wrap the text you want to change in a span

```
<a href="link.html"><span>Some text</span> <img src="image.jpg" /></a> 

$('a span').html( 'new text' );
```

Comment: No can't do that, as the elements are dynamically build from some other source.

Comment: This is however, the best answer for most people.

Answer (score 14):

My solution, though a little late.

```
$('a').each(function() {
    var contents = $(this).contents();
    if (contents.length > 0) {
        if (contents.get(0).nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
            $(this).html('NEW TEXT').append(contents.slice(1));
        }
    }
});
```

Some notes:

1. `contents()` includes text nodes, unlike `children()`.
2. It is necessary to create a *copy* of the contents via `var contents = ...` or else the remaining elements are lost forever once replaced by `$(this).html('NEW TEXT')`.
3. The `length` check is optional but recommended.
4. The `nodeType` check is optional but recommended.

Comment: This seems like the ideal way to go. This would also work:
$(this).contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType == 3;
}).each( function() { this.nodeValue = "whatever"; })

Comment: does this preserve events bound to the children?

Comment: It does not because it affects the innerHTML property. See @jim_kastrin's answer for a solution that does.

Answer (score 13):

An alternative way would be to use the `contents()` method as follows:

Given

```
<a href="link.html">Some text <img src="image.jpg" /></a>
```

you can replace `'Some text'` with jQuery

```
var text = $('a').contents().first()[0].textContent;
$('a').contents().first()[0].textContent = text.replace("Some text", "Other text");
```

jsFiddle example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dimitrios_87/cumgp2d5/).

The idea of `contents()` was inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9956388/how-to-change-only-text-node-in-element) question, answered by user charlietfl.

Comment: This seems to be the most complete answer, since any event listeners binded to the child HTML nodes will not be affected by the changes.

Comment: I still had issues with things breaking with this method, but Darryl Ceguerra's answer worked perfectly

Answer (score 12):

You can change it by .contents()

```
$('.yourElement').contents()[0].data = 'New Data';
```

where in your case the "[0].data" is your text data

Comment: best solution here, thanks a lot! isn't affecting any event listeners bounded to the html.

Comment: Worked perfectly with jquery datatables

Answer (score 2):

just use some plain js functionality:

$('a')[0].firstChild.nodeValue = "New Text";

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
$('a').live('click', function(){
    var $img = $(this).find('img'); 
    $(this).text('changed');
    $(this).append($img);
});
```

Comment: This will not work as it will replace the whole inner part including the holding HTML elements.

Answer (score 1):

An efficient and robust way that doesn't require you to know what the inner elements are or what the text is:

```
var $a = $('a');
var inner = '';
$a.children.html().each(function() {
    inner = inner + this.outerHTML;
});
$a.html('New text' + inner);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add in a `<span>` element and change the text of that element, e.g.:

```
<a href="link.html"><span id="foo">Some text</span><img src="image.jpg" /></a>
```

Then, you can call from jQuery:

```
$("#foo").html("Other text");
```

And your result will effectively be:

```
<a href="link.html"><span id="foo">Other text</span><img src="image.jpg" /></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an improvement I've made to the jquery.uniform library.
Specifically the `$.uniform.update()` function.
I took the idea from acheong87 and changed it a bit.

The idea is to change the text in a span but preserve the inner HTML and event bindings.
No need to store and append HTML this way.

```
if ($e.is("input[type=button]")) {
    spanTag = $e.closest("span");
    var contents = spanTag.contents();

    if (contents.length) {
        var text = contents.get(0);

        // Modern browsers support Node.TEXT_NODE, IE7 only supports 3
        if (text.nodeType == 3)
            text.nodeValue = $e.val();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I added a jQuery function for that need.

you may need to convert the html-entities to text representation, so i added `decodeEntities` function.

```
function decodeEntities(encodedString) {
 if (typeof encodedString != "string") return encodedString;
 if (!encodedString) return "";
 var textArea = document.createElement('textarea');
 textArea.innerHTML = encodedString;
 return textArea.value;
}
jQuery.fn.textOnly = function(n) {
  if (this.length > 0)
   $(this).html(decodeEntities($(this).html()).replace($(this).text(), n));
  return $(this);
 }
```

Usage example
  `$('selector').textOnly('some text')`

Answer (score 0):

My generic version:

```
let button = $('#yourElement');
button.html(button.html().replace(button[0].innerText, "New Text"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Shorthand for more elements and leading text to change:

```
elemshtml = '';
$("a *").each(function(){elemshtml +=$(this)[0].outerHTML});
$("a").html('Some text' + elemshtml);
```