# How to change only text node in element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have next html:

```
<label for="user_name">
  <abbr title="required">*</abbr>
  Name
</label>
```

And I want to change label caption to `Title` with jquery. So I do

```
$('label[for=user_name]').html('Title')
```

And it replaces all inner html (including `abbr` tag)

So, what's the easiest way to replace only `Name`?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

If you use `contents()` method it will also return text nodes. Since jQuery doesn't have text node methods, convert last node to a DOM node

```
$('label[for="user_name"]').contents().last()[0].textContent='Title';
```

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/yPAST/1/

Comment: Interesting.. I have only one label per input, so it's appropriate for me

Comment: Note: the `textContent` property is *not* available in IE before version 9.

Answer (score 50):

Sorry for the late reply... But here is a way to do so using only jQuery:

```
$('label').contents().last().replaceWith('Title');
```

Comment: Note that a string to `replaceWith` is treated like HTML; if it contains tags it will be parsed to DOM elements.

Comment: These answers are good, so +1, but its brittle to navigate the DOM like this. When using jQuery it's a good idea to avoid .first(), .last(), .prev(), .next(), etc.

Answer (score 3):

***[It may not be the prettiest way, but this works:](http://jsfiddle.net/d7VCN/)***

```
var $label = $('label[for=user_name]');
$label.html($label.html().replace("Name", "Title"));
```

Comment: oops!! same answer i have posted..getting so much late :(

Answer (score 1):

You can select only the `abbr` element, store it, and then replace the whole content with the stored element plus the changed caption:

```
​$('label[for="user_name"]').each(function(){
   var a = $(this).children('abbr');
   $(this).html(a).append('Title');
});
```

See this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZqDzq/)**​

Answer (score 1):

you can use `replace` accomplish this

```
  var html = $('label[for=user_name]').html().replace('Name','Testing');
  $('label[for=user_name]').html(html);
```

check it : http://jsfiddle.net/DyzMJ/

Answer (score 1):

Evans solution added to jquery fn to make it's use comfortable:

```
// get/change node content not children
jQuery.fn.content = function( n ){
    var o = $(this).clone();
    var c = o.children().remove();
    if (typeof n === "string" ){
        o.html(n);
        $(this).html(c).append(n);
    }
    return o.html();
}
```

Usage :`$('myselector').content('NewContentString');`

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution that worked for the most browsers

```
$('label[for="user_name"]').contents().last()[0].nodeValue = 'Title';
```

This one came close but gave issues in ie8 since textContent is not supported

```
$('label[for="user_name"]').contents().last()[0].textContent='Title';
```

Comment: Note: the `textContent` property is *not* available in IE before version 9.

Answer (score 0):

if you are manipulating more than 1 label you can select each label and replace text with jquery:

```
$('label[for="user_name"]').contents().last().replaceWith("Title");
```

and for the second label :

```
$('label[for="user_lastname"]').contents().last().replaceWith("Title2");
```

and so on ...