# Django: Update Page Information Without Refreshing

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django, database

I've been trying to make this portion of my website update whenever a button is pressed:

[image: Coins]

In my template, I access this information through `{{ request.user.profile.coins }}`:

```
<span class="status">Balance:&nbsp;{{ request.user.profile.coins }}
  <img class="coin-img" src="{% static 'assets/coin.png' %}" height="40px" width="auto">
</span>
```

I was looking into the process and I attempted to use an AJAX function to call this view:

```
@login_required(login_url='users/login')

def coin_increase(request):
    """
    Function based view for increasing a user's coin balance
    """
    if request.is_ajax():
        try:
            user = request.user
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404("No user matches the given query.")
        user.profile.coins += 5
        user.save()
        return render(request, 'home.html', {'home': home})
    else:
        raise Http404
```

The AJAX function is as follows:

```
function update_coins() {
    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "/coins",
      data: {},
      success: function(data) {
        alert("test");
      }
    })
  };
```

How can I get this to work?

Comment: If you're having throubles updating the content of the DOM, put your template html code too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess that `home.html` is the template of the whole page, which contains the portion of interest.

The problem is here:

```
return render(request, 'home.html', {'home': home})
```

You don't need to render the whole page to update just that portion. You only need to know the new value for `user.profile.coins`.
The most used technique is to serialize that data into a format that javascript can understand: JSON.

Not sure about what is your version of django, maybe this will work:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
return JsonResponse({'coins':user.profile.coins})
```

Then:

```
function update_coins() {
    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "/coins",
      data: {},
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data) // check out how data is structured

        // Update the coin amount
        $('.status').contents()[0].textContent = 'Balance&nbsp'+data.coins
      }
    })
  };
```

Comment: I get `Object { coins: 6725 }` in the console

Comment: Good :) now, use jquery to select the DOM element containing the coin amount and update it with `data.coins`.
If you're not familiar with jquery selectors, post your html and I'll help you

Comment: My HTML looks like:
`  <span class="status">Balance:&nbsp;{{ request.user.profile.coins }}<img class="coin-img" src="{% static 'assets/coin.png' %}" height="40px" width="auto"></span`,

So I should do $( ".status" ).something(data.coins)?

Comment: Use `$('.status').contents()[0].textContent = 'Balance&nbsp'+data.coins`.
See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9956388/how-to-change-only-text-node-in-element for further informations

Comment: For me it doe not work: here I have some questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58060402/two-submit-inputs-within-one-form-and-ajax-in-django