# Two submit inputs within one form and ajax in Django

Tags: javascript, html, django

This is the third time I ask this question, unfortunately there is no expert who can answer this simple question.

Without javascript code the method within `view.py` works perfectly both for save and calc, two submit for one form. However when I use ajax, it fails (because of `e.preventDefault();`), here is my code:

**html**

```
<form method="post" id="idForm" name="fmr1" action = "/myproject/save/" 
enctype="multipart/form-data">
....
<input type="submit" name="save" value="Save">
<input type="submit" name="calc" value="Calculate">
</form>
```

**js**

```
$("#idForm").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
    var frm = $('#idForm');

$.ajax({
    type: frm.attr('method'),
    url: frm.attr('action'),
    data: frm.serialize(),
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data.mylist)
    },
    error: function (data) {
        alert("ajax fails")
    }
    });

});
```

**views**

```
if request.method == 'POST' and 'calc' in request.POST:
    print("runs calc form")
    mylist= [5]
    return JsonResponse({'mylist':mylist})
```

**Question**

Now the difficulty is in "'calc' in request.POST", so it does not run when I add ajax or id="idForm" to the form.

I need "'calc' in request.POST" since I have to run "save" as well.

Both will have to run inside one method in views.

What can be the reason that javascript (`e.preventDefault();`) prevents it from running correctly?

How to fix it?

Comment: I think I know the reason, but I dont know how to fix it. e.preventDefault does not let the submit buttons run, it locks the form somehow, therefore with e.preventDefault, it fails.

Comment: my suggestion would be remove submit calls do it on simple button clicks define onclick function it should work type='submit' is making this singular so you can avoid prevent default here just call the ajax request and check on server side

Comment: okay, I will try. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one answered this question. With ajax two button one form did not work, I used one button and one input:

```
    <input type="submit"  name="save" id="save" value="Save">
    <button type="button" onclick="sendData()">Calculate</button>
```

this worked for me. In views I implemented two methods.