# Django: Update Page Information Without Redirecting

Tags: javascript, html, django

I have this code:

**html**

```
<form method="post" id="idForm" name="frm1" action = "/myproject/save/"
 enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
....
<input type="submit"  name="save" id="save" value="Save">
</form>

<span class="status">Value: &nbsp;{{ request.mylist}} </span>
```

**js code**

```
$(document).on('submit', '#idForm',function(e){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '{% url "myproject:save_form" %}',
        data: {},
        success:function(json){
    $('.status').contents()[0].textContent = data.mylist
        },
        error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
    alert("ajax error")
    }
});
});
```

**views**

```
if request.method == 'POST' and 'save' in request.POST:
    print("runs save form")
    mylist= [5]
    return JsonResponse({'mylist':mylist})
```

**Question:**

When I click on Save button, It is redirected to a page with 
*{"mylist": [5]}*

How can I make it update only the status part, Value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use simple a button

`<button type="button" onclick="sendData()">Save/button>`

instead of this

`<input type="submit"  name="save" id="save" value="Save">`

Make this a function

```
    function sendData(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '{% url "myproject:save_form" %}',
            data: {
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
        formdata: JSON.stringify($("#idForm").serialize()) 
},
            success:function(json){
        let result = json.mylist[0];
        $("#status").html(result);
    },
            error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
        alert("ajax error")
        } 
}); 
}
```

You should also pass `csrfmiddlewaretoken`token  in data of ajax to csrf middle trust your request.

You can do the update in ajax success callback.

**Update**

At server side you can get the serialized data like this

```
if request.method == 'POST' and 'save' in request.POST:
    print("runs save form")
    data=json.loads(request.POST.get('formdata'))
    mylist= [5]
    return JsonResponse({'mylist':mylist})
```

Comment: just curious, does it submit the form into views? I am trying right now.

Comment: yes it does try and let me know and see you have this extra check here for save so make it `<button type="button" onclick="sendData()" name="save">Save/button>`

Comment: okay, I am trying, btw, can you please take a look into this, I spent a lot of time, but cant fix it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58060402/two-submit-inputs-within-one-form-and-ajax-in-django

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works, but it does not submit the form into views. I debug, but it has nothing. The method runs but no form info. Do you know the reason? I test using: request.POST.get(name), without js it works.

Comment: yes because you are not passing any data you can serialize the whole form convert it into a json string and revert it back on server side use this for serializing form try doing `$("idForm").serialize() I ll update the answer

Comment: "'save' in request.POST" should be removed?

Comment: It does not react at all now.

Comment: I think it would be useful here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58060402/two-submit-inputs-within-one-form-and-ajax-in-django  to check if it is single button its your choice

Comment: check in web browser console must be a syntax error in js code

Comment: okay, I fixed several things, when I use data=json.loads(request.POST.get('formdata')), it gets nothing, I have an input field inside the form, I type: data=json.loads(request.POST.get('name')), it triggers an error: json object must be a str,...not None, Because request.POST.get('name') return None. So it shows that there is no data of the form still inside the method.

Comment: Hmm I think then see what you get when you do `$("idForm").serialize()` in console or find an alternative to serilize form data. You can do it manually but it helps in large forms

Comment: okay, I think this is because of  # before idForm (#idForm), you can update it. now it works. I will accept it after checking..

Comment: `$("#idForm")` is correct we are selecting element by id in jquery that way