# How to set text to both anchor and small tags using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Hi I am trying to set the text to both anchor and small in the following snippet

```
 <li id="TabA" class="done"><a href="#abc">Step 1<br /><small>Step</small></a></li>
```

And Jquery code

```
 var TabToggle = $("#TabA").clone();
TabToggle.find("small").text("First");
TabToggle.find("a").text("First")
TabToggle.find("a").attr("href", "#First" );
```

The problem is it is not able to set  the text to small tag.It is replacing all contents inside  anchor.Thanks in advance.

Comment: id should be unique on context use class

Comment: 1. IDs should be unique, you should update the tab's ID after using `clone()`. 2. Using `text()` on the `<a>` will completely remove any child elements that are inside.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change only text node in element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9956388/how-to-change-only-text-node-in-element)

Comment: Easiest option is to wrap the "step 1" text in a span and use `$("a span").text("First")` - other option is to use `.contents()`.  See linked duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

This because of your call on line 3: you are replacing the whole content of the `a` tag  which contains the `small` tag.

So you have 2 solutions:

1. Surround the text `Step 1` with a `span` tag and update his content.
2. Updates the `html` content of the `a` tag. You give it the `small` content at the same time.

**Solution 1**

```js
var tab = $("#TabA");
var span = tab.find("span");
var small = tab.find("small");
var anchor = tab.find("a");
span.text("First");
small.text("First");
anchor.attr("href", "#First");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="TabA" class="done"><a href="#abc"><span>Step 1</span><br /><small>Step</small></a></li>
```

**Solution 2**

```js
var tab = $("#TabA");
var anchor = tab.find("a");
anchor.html("First<br><small>First</small>").attr("href", "#First");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="TabA" class="done"><a href="#abc">Step 1<br /><small>Step</small></a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the first DOM text child as described in the comments but it may not work if you have a more complex content.

I suggest you to create on the fly the DOM arborescence.

```js
var new_link = $("<a/>");
new_link.attr( "href", "#First" );
new_link.html( "First<br/>" );
new_link.append( $("<small/>").html( "First" ) );

$("#TabA a").replaceWith( new_link );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li id="TabA" class="done">
  <a href="#abc">
    Step 1<br />
    <small>Step</small>
  </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

An easier solution, try using append:

```js
var val = $("#TabA > a").children().html("First");
$("#TabA > a").html('First').append(val).attr("href", "#First" );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="TabA" class="done">
    <a href="#abc">Step 1<br />
        <small>Step</small>
    </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var TabToggle = $("#TabA").clone();
var cache = TabToggle.find("a").children();
TabToggle.find("a").text(GroupData.Text).append(cache);
```

This worked.