# Change text of td element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying to change a text of a `td` element however I am not able to make it work:

http://jsfiddle.net/9HkWH/

What could be wrong in that fiddle?

Actually this is just my first step to do my actual goal that is to prettify a date using:

http://timeago.yarp.com/

**Updated:**

Where I need to do:

```
$(function() {
   $('td[kind="date"]').html("Hello?");
})
```

Comment: You need to escape those quotes or did you want to concatenate? Something is wrong check the syntax highlighting...

Comment: oops sorry, I was thinking in java haha. Anyway, I updated the fiddle already, but still does not work

Comment: Hey, don't downvote me! :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple problems

1. Your script has a syntactical error, the quotes are not properly escaped
2. Your html is not valid, there is no opening/closing `<table` tags
3. Selector `p[kind=date]` is invalid since there is no `p` element, a `td` has the attribute `kind="date"`.

So

```
$(function() {
   $('td[kind="date"]').html("test");
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/W2MAk/)

Comment: Arun, I have updated my answer with this code you have but still does not work in jsFiddle.

Comment: Oh I get it, sorry, this is result of a GWT developer tinkering in Javascript :-)

Answer (score 1):

First,you write the wrong selector,there is not 'p' element,your should try

`$("td[kind='date']").html("test");`

Second,the quotation marks in selector should be single not double.

Last and most important,your html code missed 'table' tag,so the html will render as text not a table,that's why your selector will not work even you change the selector by other's advices.

Check this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9HkWH/14/),it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please refer the below code.

```
function changeText() {
    $("#demoTable td").each(function () {
       $(this).html().replace("8: Tap on APN and Enter <B>www</B>", "");
    }
}
```

[Replace text inside td using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13816944/replace-text-inside-td-using-jquery)