# Replace text in label that has an input inside, without affecting input

Tags: jquery

I have this code:

```
<label class="hulkapps_check_option">
<input type="checkbox" data-price="4000.00">
Basic banner design (+$ 4000.00)
</label>
```

I need to find the text ".00" in the label and replace it with " MXN" but without affecting the input. Whenver I try anything to replace the text it removes the input inside the label. How can I replace a piece of text in the label, without removing the input inside of it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I select text nodes with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298750/how-do-i-select-text-nodes-with-jquery)

Comment: Possibly duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13817123/2181514

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first option is it put your text inside a `<span>`, then it will be easily accessible from jQuery.  jQuery isn't designed to handle text-only nodes very well.

If you can't change the HTML for whatever reason, then you can use `.contents()` and `.this.nodeType === 3` (where 3 is a text node).

```js
$('.hulkapps_check_option').contents().each(function() {
  if (this.nodeType === 3) {
    this.textContent
      ? this.textContent = this.textContent.replace(/\.00/g, " MX")
      : this.innerText = this.innerText.replace(/\.00/g, " MX")
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="hulkapps_check_option">
  <input type="checkbox" data-price="4000.00">
  Basic banner design (+$ 4000.00)
</label>
```

You *could* use `.html()` to get the text with the input.

While this works in *this scenario* - it's too brittle to work in the general case (eg if you wanted to change all "put" with "POST" then you'd get `<inPOST type="checkbox"`).

You also lose any events you might have had against any elements inside the label.

```js
var h = $(".hulkapps_check_option").html().replace(/\.00/g, " MXN");
$(".hulkapps_check_option").html(h);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label class="hulkapps_check_option_before">
    <input type="checkbox" data-price="4000.00">
    Basic banner design (+$ 4000.00)
</label>

<hr/>

<label class="hulkapps_check_option">
    <input type="checkbox" data-price="4000.00">
    Basic banner design (+$ 4000.00)
</label>
```

Comment: This solution works! Thank you for that. I don't really understand the code. Could you please provide a bit of explanation to what this is: .textContent and where it comes from? and also the interrogation and : symbol on the following lines? Where can I find more information about what they are and how they're used? 

Also, could you explain what type of formatting this is? (/\.00/g, " MX"). What's the /\ and /g?

Thank you so much!

Comment: `:?` - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259982/how-do-you-use-the-conditional-operator-in-javascript

Comment: `.textContent` - in jquery we do `$("#id").text()` - the `.text()` part translates to `.textContent` - but in some browsers that doesn't exist, so you have to use `.innerText` instead.  Good old browser-wars / incompatibilities (that no doubt someone will say no longer exists).  That's partly why jquery is so popular, no need to worry about it.  It's micro-optimisation to use `.textContent` rather than `$().text()`.

Comment: `.replace(regex, replacement)` - use `.replace(/regex/g, "replacement)` where `//` provide the regex and `/g` indicates all occurrences.   `\.` = match "." as `.` is "match any single character" and `00` means "match 00"

Comment: TBH, not sure `$().text` works with text nodes, so that's why I left it using .textContent / .innerText.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/13817123/2181514

Comment: amazing explanation for every bit. Thank you so much for taking the time to provide more information!

Comment: another question if you kindly have the time... why do you have to add regex inside of the .replace()? Why wouldn't this work?`.replace(".00"," MXN")`?

Comment: Replace can use *either* a regex or a string.  You can use the string to replace, it's the equivalent in this case as the "regex" is very static.  You could change it to `/\.\d\d/g` which would remove *any* decimal places, not use ".00"

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code, I just check its working for me.

```js
$(".hulkapps_check_option").text(function() {
  return $(this).text().replace(".00", " MXN");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label class="hulkapps_check_option_before">
    <input type="checkbox" data-price="4000.00">
    Basic banner design (+$ 4000.00)
</label>

<hr/>

<label class="hulkapps_check_option">
    <input type="checkbox" data-price="4000.00">
    Basic banner design (+$ 4000.00)
</label>
```

Comment: Hi, I converted your code to a snippet - as you can see, `.text()` removes the checkbox.

Comment: I tried this and it removes the checkbox: [link](http://prntscr.com/nxovrr)

Answer (score 0):

This would be a way to achieve your goal using the standard Javascript DOM API:

```js
const label = document.querySelector('.hulkapps_check_option');
const labelTextNode = label.childNodes[2];
label.removeChild(label.childNodes[2]);
label.appendChild(new Text(labelTextNode.wholeText.replace('.00', 'MXN')));
```

```html
<label class="hulkapps_check_option">
  <input type="checkbox" data-price="4000.00">
  Basic banner design (+$ 4000.00)
</label>
```