# How can i empty the element except one element in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

Example,

```
 <td id="example">
   Something is inside here.
   <button id="paymentBtn">pay</button>
 </td>
```

What i want to do is, `"only emtpy"` before payment button and insert a new thing like this,

```
<td id="example">
   Deleted old one, and inserted new one.
   <button id="paymentBtn">pay</button>
 </td>
```

I know i can use

```
$("#paymentBtn").before("inserted new one");
```

but how can i empty?

If i empty example. it blows everything and

```
 $("#paymentBtn").before().empty();
```

This doesn't work :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery change inner text but preserve html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5232862/jquery-change-inner-text-but-preserve-html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$($("#paymentBtn").get(0).previousSibling).remove();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/tC8qK/)

As suggested also you can

```
$('#add').click(function(){
    $("#paymentBtn").before("<span>inserted new one</span>");
})
$('#remove').click(function(){
    $("#paymentBtn").prev('span').remove();
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/S222D/)

Answer (score 0):

i'd ideally have my html like this..where text is not directly inside :

```
<td id="example">
   <span>Something is inside here.</span>
   <button id="paymentBtn">pay</button>
 </td>
```

Then I'd want my html to be this later:

```
<td id="example">
   <span>Deleted old one, and inserted new one.</span>
   <button id="paymentBtn">pay</button>
 </td>
```

And, then I will do this:

```
$('#example').find('span').html('Deleted old one, and inserted new one.');
```

Or this, `$('#paymentBtn').prev().html('Deleted old one, and inserted new one.');`

Answer (score 0):

One of the andwer is, store the text into the `<span class="deleteThis"></span>`

```
 <td id="example">
   <span class="deleteThis"> Something is inside here.</span>
   <button id="paymentBtn">pay</button>
 </td>
```

And remove it, or rewrite with some other text:

```
$("#paymentBtn").parent().find(".deleteThis").empty().html("Changed");
```

Or navigate right from parent:

```
$("#example .deleteThis").empty().html("Changed");
```

Second answer is, that you can remove everything but one element:

```
var oldElem = $("#paymentBtn").clone();
$('#example').empty().append("Deleted successfully.").append(oldElem);
```

You clone the element/s you donot want to remove, empty parent and restore cloned element/s.