# How can I replace the text in an HTML tag but not in an href link?

Tags: javascript

I want to write a Javascript function to change the text google in an HTML tag: example:

```
 <a href='http://google.com'>google</a>
```

How can I change the text in an HTML tag "google" but not change the content "http://google.com" that is in an href link?

Comment: By changing the `textContent` of the node?

Comment: Just set tag's innerHTML attribute.

Comment: You can Check this This question at Stackoverflow itself http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5232862/jquery-change-inner-text-but-preserve-html

Comment: Well you could do it with php, set a var, then echo it and use Ajax to refresh everyone you change it.

Comment: check this https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/cknLxxwb/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/c48jzofk/

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Vanilla JS (plain javascript) then you need to find the `a` tag by looping among all `a` and finding the one with `href` `http://google.com` and then replace it's `innerHTML`.

```
var els = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var i = 0, l = els.length; i < l; i++) {
    var el = els[i];
    if (el.href === 'http://google.com') {
        el.innerHTML = "New Content";
    }
}
```

**Explaination:**

**A.** `document.getElementsByTagName` will return you the list of all elements matching the passed tag.

**B.** `el.href` will get you the `href` of the `a`.

**C.** `el.innerHTML = "New Content"` will set the new content.