# How to change sibling text of element without changing html using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, text, replace

I'm trying to replace text only, but without touching any other tags.

```
<p>
    <a href="login.php">
        <i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> 
        Login
    </a>
</p>
```

```js
$('p').each(function() {
    $(this).text($(this).text.replace('Login', 'Anmeldung')); 
});
```

Bad result:

```
<p>
    Anmeldung       
</p>
```

Result as I would like it to be:

```
<p>
    <a href="login.php">
        <i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> 
        Anmeldung
    </a>
</p>
```

How can I do this? This is only a sample, deeper structure of `p` tags can be completely different.

Comment: If the only element you can select is the `p` you will need to recurse through the child elements and nodes and replace the `text()` within that element directly. Replacing the `text()` of the parent will have the effect of removing the HTML

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JQuery change inner text but preserve html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5232862/jquery-change-inner-text-but-preserve-html)

Comment: You want to change part of text or all of it?

Comment: Why only with jQuery? It's almost like you don't know that jQuery isn't a language...

Comment: @evolutionxbox jQuery is great for operations on the DOM. Why should he use a more complex solution with vanilla js if he's using jQuery in his application anyway?

Comment: @KilianStinson - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/39613834/989920

Comment: @evolutionxbox The answer you linked is using jQuery as solution and is wrong anyway. What's your point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.html()` instead of `.text()`
This preserves your html tags

```js
$('p').each(function() {
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace('Login', 'Anmeldung')); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
    <a href="login.php">
        <i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> 
        Login
    </a>
</p>
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/6q581b2u/) using your example.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap text you want to replace in a span or something.

```
<p>
    <a href="login.php">
        <i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> 
        <span class="replace-login">Login</span>
    </a>
</p>
```

and js

```
    $('.replace-login').each(function() {
       $(this).text($(this).text.replace('Login', 'Anmeldung')); 
   });
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a solution without changing the HTML. Because this would be a lot of work!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change all text sibling of `i`, select `i` tag in `p` and use [`Node.nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling) property to selecting sibling text after element and change it.

```js
$("p > a > i")[0].nextSibling.nodeValue = "Anmeldung";
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
    <a href="login.php">
        <i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> 
        Login
    </a>
</p>
```

But if you want to replace part of text, use this code

```js
$("p > a").html(function(i, html){
    return html.replace("Login", "Anmeldung");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
    <a href="login.php">
        <i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> 
        Login
    </a>
</p>
```

Comment: The structure inside `p` is not given. It is just an example so your solution won't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<p>
  <a href="login.php">
    <i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> 
    Login
  </a>
</p>

$('p').each(function() {
  $(this).find("a").text($(this).find("a").text.replace('Login', 'Anmeldung')); 
});
```

Comment: `This is only a sample, deeper structure of p tags can be completely different.`. Also your code will wipe out the `i` in the `a`

Comment: what about <i></i> tag ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this  [DEMO LINK HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/hnfRe/402/)

```
<p>
    <a href="login.php">
        <i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> 
        Login
    </a>
</p>
```

JS..

```
$('p').each(function() {
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace('Login', 'Anmeldung')); 
});
```

> > http://jsfiddle.net/hnfRe/402/

Comment: Can you include the fiddle into you answer, rather than linking offsite?

Answer (score 0):

use html instead of text function. . .

```
$('p').html($(this).html().replace('Login', 'Anmeldung'));
```