# How do you avoid editing tags inside of tags when replacing characters inside of a tag

Tags: javascript, html, replace, getelementsbytagname

So lets say you have HTML that looks something like this:

```
<p>This text is <b>bold</b></p>
```

and this Javascript:

```
var obs = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
var obsreplace = obs[0].innerHTML.replace(/b/gi, "g");
obs[0].innerHTML = obsreplace;
```

This will change the HTML to this:

```
<p>This text is <g>gold</g></p>
```

But what if I want to change it to:

```
<p>This text is <b>gold</b></p>
```

and leave the bold tags unchanged?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JQuery change inner text but preserve html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5232862/jquery-change-inner-text-but-preserve-html)

Comment: Also meant to say, I can't help but read the title of this post in Xzibit's voice (Yo dawg, we heard you like tags...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use `childNodes`, and run your replace against each of those. That will capture text nodes separately from elements. By recursively looping through each child element until there are only text nodes left, you can safely run your replace command against all text in the element.

```js
function safeReplace(elem, replaceFn){
  let nodes = elem.childNodes, i = -1
  while(++i < nodes.length){
    let node = nodes[i]
    if(node.nodeType == 3){ //signifies a text node
      node.textContent = replaceFn(node.textContent)
    } else {
      safeReplace(node, replaceFn)
    }
  }
}
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(){
  safeReplace(document.getElementById('testDiv'), function(str){
    return str.replace(/e/gi, '_E_')
  })
})
```

```html
<div id="testDiv">
This div has outer content, as well as <p>a paragraph containing a <span>spanned text</span> in the middle</p>More text.</div>

<button>Replace Text</button>
```

Comment: Question asked for replacing text within a particular tag, not replacing all matched text within DOM nodes.

Comment: @JonathanHamel That's two different ways of describing the same action, it just depends on which DOM node you choose. The structured state of `div` and `p` tags makes it easier to show that they're not getting removed, but the same concept applies to `b` tags inside a `p` if you pass the `p` into that function

Answer (score 1):

So, two solutions, replace with regex keeping the matched groups, or use the `getElementsByTagName`? For sure you have to check the length of obs and bold before doing any operation on the elements, making sure there are no errors.

```js
var obs = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
var bold = obs[0].getElementsByTagName("b")[0];
bold.innerHTML = "gold";

var obs = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
var replaceHtml = obs[1].innerHTML.replace(/(<b>).*?(<\/b>)/, "$1gold$2");
obs[1].innerHTML = replaceHtml;
```

```html
<p>This text is <b>bold</b></p>
<p>This text is <b>bold</b></p>
```